# HTML::ELEMENT not finding all elements

Tags: html, perl, module

I have this snippet of html:

```
<li class="result-row" data="2">
<a href="https://localhost/1.html" class="result-image gallery empty"></a>

<p class="result-info">
    <span class="icon icon-star" role="button">
        <span class="screen-reader-text">favorite this post</span>
    </span>

    <time class="result-date" datetime="2018-12-04 09:21" title="Tue 04 Dec 09:21:50 AM">Dec  4</time>

<a href="https://localhost/1.html" data="2" class="result-title hdrlnk">Link Text</a>
```

and this perl code (not production, so no quality comments are necessary)

```
my $root = $tree->elementify();
my @rows = $root->look_down('class', 'result-row');

my $item = $rows[0];
say $item->dump;
my $date = $item->look_down('class', 'result-date');
say $date;
my $title = $item->look_down('class', 'result-title hdrlnk');
```

All outputs are as I expected except `$date` isn't defined.

When I look at the `$item->dump`, it looks like the time element doesn't show up in the output.  Here's a snippet of the output from `$item->dump` where I would expect to see a `<time...>` element. All it shows is the text from the time element.

```
<li class="result-row" data="2"> @0.1.9.3.2.0
<a class="result-image gallery empty" href="https://localhost/1.html"> @0.1.9.3.2.0.0
<p class="result-info"> @0.1.9.3.2.0.1
<span class="icon icon-star" role="button"> @0.1.9.3.2.0.1.0
" "
<span class="screen-reader-text"> @0.1.9.3.2.0.1.0.1
"favorite this post"
" "
" Dec 4 "
<a class="result-title hdrlnk" data="2" href="https://localhost/1.html"> @0.1.9.3.2.0.1
.2
"Link Text..."
" "
...
```

I've not used [HTML::Element](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Element) before. I rtfmed and didn't see any tag exclusions and I did a search of the package code for tags white/black lists (which wouldn't make sense, but neither does leaving out the time tag).

Does anyone know why the time element is not showing up in the dump and any search for it turns up nothing?

As an fyi, the rest of the code searches and finds elements without issue, it just appears to be the time tag that's missing.

Comment: It doesn't appear to understand the `time` tag.  I can't `look_down` for it either, not even using `_tag  => 'time'`.  Don't know why (I may or may not be able to look more later)

Comment: Try un-setting the [`ignore_unknown` attribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder#ignore_unknown). Presumably by `$root->ignore_unknown(0)` before any parsing (but it didn't do anything for me, on v5.16).  Note that with that any tag-like thingy is going to be included in the parse tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML::TreeBuilder [does not support HTML5 tags](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=84526). Consider [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) as an alternative that keeps up with the living HTML standard. I can't show how your whole code would look with Mojo::DOM since you've only shown a piece, but the Mojo::DOM equivalent of look_down is `find` (returns a Mojo::Collection arrayref) or `at` (returns the first element found or undef), both taking a [CSS selector](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM::CSS).

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  As the thread mentions, un-setting the attribute `ignore_unknown`, which by default instructs the parser to ignore unknown (unsupported) tags, should fix that (while it will then include in the parse tree any tag-like construct). However, I couldn't get this to work as adding `$root->ignore_unknown(0);` didn't change things in my tests (on v5.16).

Comment: @zdim I suspect that HTML::Parser ignores the tags itself before they even get to HTML::TreeBuilder's event handling. Or possibly is doing something else with them, as unlike Mojo::DOM it seems to modify the input to be a "proper HTML page". But it's difficult to verify since HTML::Parser is XS code and rather opaque to use on its own.